# MAUI - Collection View Pre Select Item background color change

Tags: maui, collectionviewsource, maui-community-toolkit, maui-windows, maui-collectionview

I am working on MAUI technology and developing Windows Application So, I have a requirement to pre-select the item in collection view and that item need to be highlighted. so, I have checked the sample code of microsoft document there also have the same issue.

Sample Microsoft Document URL
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/selection?view=net-maui-7.0#multiple-preselection

So, I tried below code. It's working but i am unable to highlight the item with background color.

DetailsPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="iOSCollectionViewPreselectedTEST.NewPage1"
             Title="DetailsPage">
    <CollectionView ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems" x:Name="collView"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="CollectionView_SelectionChanged">
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="2"/>
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <VerticalStackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding .}" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups >
                        <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState Name="Selected">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Blue" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</ContentPage>
```

DetailsPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class DetailsPage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string>(new List<string> {
        "Employee1", "Employee2", "Employee3", "Employee4"
    });
    public string SelectedItem { get; set; }
    public DetailsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
        SelectedItem = Items[1];
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem));
    }

    private void CollectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var preSelectedItem = e.CurrentSelection;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is just the case as you said.

And there is a known issue about this, you follow it up here: [CollectionView Pre Select Item background color not change on windows](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/15666).

Thanks for your support for maui.

Best Regards.